# How to Remove/Disable/Always Accept HTML5 Canvas Image?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, source-code

How can I disable the patch and limit its influence? In older TBB builds this patch could be removed pretty easy. Is there still an easy way?
The difficult way seems to revert these changes: https://gitweb.torproject.org/torbrowser.git/blob/master:/src/current-patches/firefox/0019-Add-canvas-image-extraction-prompt.patch

Or at least, can I allow any website I visit, without having the pop-up/to click each time?
I already checked about:config. Sadly, there does not seem to be an entry.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**WARNING: the following setting stores a history of your pages which might oppose your reason for using Tor.**

I haven't found a solution for all sites but here is one that at least remembers the option for visited pages:

Enter `about:config` in address bar, search for `permissions.memory_only` and set it to `false`. Next time you visit a page click `Never for this site`.

Comment: how to set it "never for all sites" ?

Answer (score 2):

The above method does not work anymore.

If you want to set to never allow for all sites, you need to go into `about:config` and look for `privacy.resistFingerprinting.autoDeclineNoUserInputCanvasPrompts` and set it to true